# Present simple only?

Tags: present-tense

my friend who is learning english, asked me to check his grammar test, he told me they only started learning present simple, text is:

(Words in CAPITAL should be put in the correct form)

However, in my opinion, it does not make sense, only using the present simple

> Kim's 19 and she's a shop assistant. She GET up early, HAVE breakfast
>   and LEAVE home at 8.30. She START work at 9.30 and FINISH at 5.30. She
>   WORK in a bookshop but she NOT LIKE reading! She GET home at 6.30 and
>   HAVE dinner with her family. She GO to bed early but she NOT READ in
>   bed!

Comment: If your friend knows both forms of Present Simple (Example: LEAVE/LEAVES; HAS/HAVE; ...) these will be easy. If your friend knows about DO/DOES with NOT they will score 100%.

Comment: In my opinion, it should be: Kim's 19 and she's a shop assistant. She gets up early, has breakfast and leaves home at 8.30. She starts work at 9.30 and finishes at 5.30. She works in a bookshop but she does not read! She gets home at 6.30 and has dinner with her family. She goes to bed early but she does not read in bed! 

What do you think?

Comment: Pretty good. You've left out one word LIKE. But the rest is fine. Since your friend is just starting to learn English, English Language for Learners https://ell.stackexchange.com/ will be much more helpful than this site.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing nonsensical in the extract. One of the comments has given us the correct version as it should be. Present simple can fairly express situations that are more or less " permanent in nature".If the situations are new or temporary we may use present continuous. It is almost Kim's DAILY LIFE where things happen in the manner of —the -sun -rises, flowers- bloom and wind- blows.

The passage has nothing wrong in it barring grammatical mistakes. It is perfectly synchronous with time and space, actual purpose of tenses.